# Regular expression for 'followed by a set of characters or nothing'

Tags: regex

I want to match the pattern *.list* if list is not part of a word or if not the `list()` method - tried variations of `\.list([^(a-zA-Z]?|\s)` but still matches .listctrl and .list() - what am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use word boundaries and a negative lookahead:

```
\.list\b(?! *\(\))
```

- `\b` is a word boundary that will fail the match for `listctrl`
- `(?! *\(\))` is a negative lookahead that will fail the match if `.list` is followed by optional spaces and `()`

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cH5rS5/1)